# Combine columns from different dataframes on timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have several dataframes with a ID, Timestamp and a value. I'm creating the final dataframe by merging the dataframes and I would like to list all the values (if any) from each dataframe based on the timestamp. Now my (wrong) final dataframe is this:

```
              Date            ID     ValDf1       ValDf2        ValDf3
104 2017-03-01 04:00:00      13971   5.333333       NaN        NaN
105 2017-03-01 06:00:00      13971   5.333333       NaN        NaN
106 2017-03-01 06:24:00      13971   5.333333       NaN        NaN
107 2017-03-01 07:00:00      13971   4.666667       NaN        NaN
108 2017-03-01 07:59:00      13971   4.000000       NaN        NaN
109 2017-03-01 08:00:00      13971   4.000000       NaN        NaN
110 2017-03-01 10:30:00      13971   3.333333       NaN        NaN
111 2017-03-01 12:00:00      13971   2.666667       NaN        NaN
112 2017-02-25 08:00:00      13971        NaN       NaN   0.000000
113 2017-02-25 12:00:00      13971        NaN       NaN   5.000000
114 2017-02-25 14:00:00      13971        NaN       NaN   5.000000
115 2017-02-25 16:03:00      13971        NaN       NaN   5.000000
116 2017-02-25 17:00:00      13971        NaN       NaN   5.000000
117 2017-02-25 18:43:00      13971        NaN       NaN   6.000000
```

Now, I would like to sort them in a unique columns based of date: for instance, like this:

```
                  Date            ID     ValDf1       ValDf2        ValDf3
104 2017-02-25 04:00:00      13971   5.333333       NaN        0.000000
105 2017-02-25 06:00:00      13971   5.333333       NaN        5.000000
106 2017-02-25 06:24:00      13971   5.333333       NaN        5.000000
107 2017-03-01 07:00:00      13971   4.666667       NaN        NaN
108 2017-03-01 07:59:00      13971   4.000000       NaN        NaN
109 2017-03-01 08:00:00      13971   4.000000       NaN        NaN
110 2017-03-01 10:30:00      13971   3.333333       NaN        NaN
111 2017-03-01 12:00:00      13971   2.666667       NaN        NaN
```

Is there a way I can do that? I tried with concat and merge, but the result is always the one I showed. Do I need to resample the dates with the resampling function?

Thank you very much

My attempt to code this final dataframe is:

```
finalDf = pd.DataFrame()
frame = [df1, df2, df3]
finalDf = pd.concat(frame)
finalDf = visScore.groupby('ID')['Date']
```

But the result is what you find before

Comment: What is the logic of  `ValDf3` from row 112 being added to row 104?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking two questions: **1.** How to correctly merge several dataframes? **2.** How to sort them in such and such way? --> If so, please clarify that, and provide more information i.e. data in code form and the actual code you've ran yourself to attempt part 1.

Comment: The data added to the final result is that it equals between the two dataframes, so at that timestamp I have a value in ValDf1 and ValDf3

Comment: DO you think I need to resample the dates and use an inner join on those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'ID']).sum()                                                                                                                                           

                   ValDf1  ValDf2  ValDf3
Date     ID                              
04:00:00 13971  5.333333     0.0     0.0
06:00:00 13971  5.333333     0.0     0.0
06:24:00 13971  5.333333     0.0     0.0
07:00:00 13971  4.666667     0.0     0.0
07:59:00 13971  4.000000     0.0     0.0
08:00:00 13971  4.000000     0.0     0.0
10:30:00 13971  3.333333     0.0     0.0
12:00:00 13971  2.666667     0.0     5.0
14:00:00 13971  0.000000     0.0     5.0
16:03:00 13971  0.000000     0.0     5.0
17:00:00 13971  0.000000     0.0     5.0
18:43:00 13971  0.000000     0.0     6.0
```

With more than one dataframe:

```
pd.concat([df, df]).groupby(['Date', 'ID']).sum()                                                                                                                               

                   ValDf1  ValDf2  ValDf3
Date     ID                              
04:00:00 13971  10.666666     0.0     0.0
06:00:00 13971  10.666666     0.0     0.0
06:24:00 13971  10.666666     0.0     0.0
07:00:00 13971   9.333334     0.0     0.0
07:59:00 13971   8.000000     0.0     0.0
08:00:00 13971   8.000000     0.0     0.0
10:30:00 13971   6.666666     0.0     0.0
12:00:00 13971   5.333334     0.0    10.0
14:00:00 13971   0.000000     0.0    10.0
16:03:00 13971   0.000000     0.0    10.0
17:00:00 13971   0.000000     0.0    10.0
18:43:00 13971   0.000000     0.0    12.0
```

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect, but before grouping I need to concatenate the 3 df into a final one. How can I do that avoiding the repetition of nans?

Comment: Because on that way it is correct, but both Date and IDs aren't index anymore like in the screenshot attached: https://imgur.com/a/GbekHMP

Comment: Edited to show with more than one dataframe. Pretty easy to see how to expand to N dataframes..